# Checking if name of a person is valid or not

Tags: python, pandas

I am working on a project in which I have to figure out if the name of a person is valid or not. One case of invalidity is a single character name.

In English, it is straight forward to figure out by checking the length.

```
if len(name) < 2:
    return 0
```

I am not sure if checking length will work out for other languages to, like 玺. I am not sure if this is one character or something else.

Can someone help me to solve this issue?

Dataset info:
countries: 125
total names: 11 Million

Comment: `len('玺')==1`; True

Comment: [Falsehoods Programmers Believe About Names](https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/) #6 is somewhat relevant, though I suspect you have discovered a falsehood not appearing on this list.

Comment: You have Sweden in there? One-letter names are legal and exists here, though not very common :P

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use a dictionary:

```
language_dict = {
'english':2,
'chinese':1
}

if len(name) < language_dict['english']:
    return 0
```

Answer (score 0):

While I can't vouch for all other languages, checking a python script with the character you provided confirms that according to Python it is still a single character.

```
print(len("玺"))

if len("玺") < 2:
    print("Single char name")
```

Another potential solution would be to check `ord(char)` (29626 for the given char) to check if it is outside the standard latin alphabet and perform additional conditional checks.